# Render email in stead of user_id but with 2 custom ids on the record - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im a bit new to Ruby on Rails so I'm hoping this isn't a stupid question.

I'm trying to make an application to store played fifa games.

This requires 2 users linked to one game, but offcourse one user can also have many games, therefore I used a many-to-many relation.

Controller:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
        before_action :authenticate_user!, exept: [:index, :show]

    def index
        @games = Game.all


    end

    def new
        @game = current_user.games.build
        @user_options = User.all.map{|u| [ u.email, u.id ] }
    end

    def create
        @user_options = User.all.map{|u| [ u.email, u.id ] }
        @game = Game.new(game_params)

        @game.home_team_user_id = current_user.id
        @game.home_team_user_name = current_user.email



               if @game.save
            redirect_to games_path, :notice => "Successfully added game!"
        else
            render 'index'
        end
    end

    def show
        @games = Game.all
    end

    def destroy
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])
        @game.destroy
        redirect_to games_path
    end


    private
    def find_game
            @game = Game.find(params[:id])    
    end

    def game_params
        params.require(:game).permit(:home_team_user_name, :home_score, :away_team_user_name, :away_score, :home_team_user_id, :away_team_user_id)
    end
end
```

View File:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right:10px">
  <!-- Default panel contents -->
  <div class="panel-heading">Played games</div>

  <!-- Table -->
          <table class="table">
             <thead>
                 <th>Home Team</th>
                 <th>Home Team Score</th>
                 <th>Away Team Score</th>
                 <th>Away Team</th>
                 <th>Added by</th>
                 <th>Actions</th>
              </thead>
                <% @games.each do |game|%> 
                 <tbody> 

              <td>
                  <%= game.home_team_user_id %>

              </td>

              <td>
                  <%= game.home_score %>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <%= game.away_score %>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <%= game.away_team_user_id %>
              </td>

                <td>

                </td>
              <td>
                  <%= link_to "Delete", game, method: :delete, data: { confrim: "Are you sure?"} %>
                </td>
                     <% end %>
              </tbody>
          </table>

        </div>
```

New Game form:

```
    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-right:10px">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Submit New Match</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <%= simple_form_for(@game) do |f| %>
                <%= f.text_field :home_score, :placeholder => "Your score" %>
                <%= f.text_field :away_score, :placeholder => "Your Opponents score" %> 

                <%= f.select(:away_team_user_id, @user_options) %>

                <%= f.submit "Submit Match", class: "btn-submit" %>
                <% end %>

     <!--     <%= form_for @game do |f| %>

                <%= collection_select(:game, :away_team_user_id, User.all, :id, :email, prompt: true ) %>
                <%= f.text_field :home_score, :placeholder => "Your score" %>
                <%= f.text_field :away_score, :placeholder => "Your Opponents score" %>


          <%= f.submit "Submit Match", class: "btn-submit" %>
          <% end %> -->
      </div>
</div>
```

Now I'm able to add games with the
home_team_user_id = current_user
away_team_user_id = user selected from dropdown menu

and offcourse the score.

However in the view the email adresses should be shown in stead of the id's.

I've tried many solutions like  <%= game.home_team_user_id.user.email %>

This gives the error : undefined method `user' for 1:Fixnum

Can anybody help me on this mather? What am I doing wrong?

Thx in advance!

ADDITIONAL QUESTION:

Hi there so I tried the last answer but I'm getting an error.

> undefined local variable or method `game' for

Controller:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, exept: [:index, :show]

def index
    @games = Game.all
    @home_user = User.select(:id, :user_name).find(game.home_team_user_id)
end

def new
    @game = current_user.games.build
    @user_options = User.all.map{|u| [ u.user_name, u.id ] }
end

def create
    @user_options = User.all.map{|u| [ u.user_name, u.id ] }

    @game = Game.new(game_params)

    @game.home_team_user_id = current_user.id

      if @game.home_score > @game.away_score

        @game.winner_id = @game.home_team_user_id
        @game.loser_id = @game.away_team_user_id

    else

        @game.winner_id = @game.away_team_user_id
        @game.loser_id = @game.home_team_user_id

        end 




    if @game.save
        redirect_to games_path, :notice => "Successfully added game!"
    else
        render 'index'
    end
end

def show
    @games = Game.all
end

def destroy
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @game.destroy
    redirect_to games_path
end


private
def find_game
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])    
end

def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:home_team_user_name, :home_score, :away_team_user_name, :away_score, :home_team_user_id, :away_team_user_id, :winner_id, :loser_id)
end
end
```

Models:
Game:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_games 
    has_many :users, through: :user_games


    belongs_to :winner, class_name: 'User' # or Team or whatever
  belongs_to :loser, class_name: 'User'

  before_validation :evaluate_score!, if: -> { home_score.present? }

  private

    def evaluate_score!
      self.winner = home_score > away_score ? home_team_user : away_team_user
      self.loser = home_score < away_score ? home_team_user : away_team_user
    end
end
```

User:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_games 
    has_many :games, through: :user_games

    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

user_game:

```
class UserGame < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :game 
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160331142037) do

  create_table "game_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id_id"
    t.integer "game_id_id"
  end

  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "home_team_user_name"
    t.string   "home_score"
    t.string   "away_team_user_name"
    t.string   "away_score"
    t.integer  "home_team_user_id"
    t.integer  "away_team_user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
    t.integer  "winner_id"
    t.integer  "loser_id"
  end

  create_table "user_games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "game_id"
    t.integer "user_id_id"
    t.integer "game_id_id"
  end

  add_index "user_games", ["game_id_id"], name: "index_user_games_on_game_id_id"
  add_index "user_games", ["user_id_id"], name: "index_user_games_on_user_id_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "win"
    t.integer  "los"
    t.integer  "draw"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: share your model code for proper answer but hopefully this : `<%= User.find(game.home_team_user_id).email %>` will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, try:

```
@home_user = User.select(:id, :email).find(game.home_team_user_id)
```

In your view:

```
<%= @home_user.email %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment, this worked for me:

```
<%= User.find(game.home_team_user_id).email %>
```

Comment: My answer is the same thing except it will perform better because you're not pulling pieces of the object you don't need.

Comment: This is very bad practice using logic in view. @toddmetheny's answer more `Rails way`. Also, your code will break if the user is not found.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have a `has_many` relation in the model, then in your view you should use:

```
<% game.home_team_users.each do |home_team| %>
 <%= home_team.email %>
<% end %>
```

Added:

I am going to ignore that you are using `@games = Game.all` in `def show`, which is the same as in `def index`. :)

The `show` should display view only related to **one** record, and `index` should be used for **all** records